# Finding count and a field from two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following two tables:

```
Table A:
--------

Id     Service

101     S1
101     S1
101     S2
101     S2
102     S4

Table B:
--------
Service   Status
S1         Active
S1         Active
S2         Inactive
S2         Inactive
S4         Cancelled

Result Required:
----------------
Id    Service   Count Status
101   S1         2    Active
101   S2         2    Inactive
102   S4         1    Cancelled
```

How can we write one sql-query to get data from these two tables as per the result required?

Many thanks for your help!

Edit:

Is there a way where in we can populate different 'count-columns' of the table simultaneously using the same sql query. For instance, if the result is required in the form of:

```
Id    Service   Active_Count Inactive_Count Cancelled_Count
---------------------------------------------------------------------
   101     S1          2            0              2
   101     S1          0            2              0
   102     S4          0            0              1
```

Comment: what's your attempt and problem you have experienced ?

Comment: please enter your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, A.service, count(1), status 
from A, B 
where A.service = B.service 
group by id, A.service, status
```

Comment: As a suggestion please dont use comma seperated joins. Its deprecated!

Comment: @R.T. as far as I know implicit joins are not deprecated. can you provide a source?

Comment: @FuzzyTree:- You may check here:- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins (*May be I should have used a bad habit instead of **deprecated***)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select id, A.service, count(1), status 
from A inner join B on A.service = B.service 
group by id, A.service, status
```